# Google Apps Script - Typewriter Effect

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to add a sort of 'typewriter effect' on my google apps script for google docs. I want to make it type out text, in this case a wikipedia article, as if a user was typing it, so add a delay. Unfortunately the function appendText(), even if you use Utilities.sleep, it still just types the entire article out as soon as the script finishes. What function would I use to accomplish something like this?

```
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
            .addItem('Start', 'myFunction')
            .addToUi();
}   

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function myFunction() {
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var text = body.editAsText();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=title&grnlimit=1');
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    for (key in json.query.pages) {
            var title = json.query.pages[key].title;
    }
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=&titles=' + title
    var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json2 = JSON.parse(response2);
    for (key in json2.query.pages) {
            var content = json2.query.pages[key].extract;
    }
    //content = content.replace(/==.*==/, '====')
    var all = title + '\n' + content;
    text.appendText("Start\n");
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    text.appendText(content);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: @JordanRunning I just added it

Comment: try flushing the google doc after each change.

Comment: I believe @ZigMandel has the right of it here. Google Docs or sheets generally batch operations, so if you write each symbol one by one, in order to optimize Google dumps it all as one. `flush()` (on document) should force it to save each change separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the document. The DocumentApp API does not have a flush method (like SpreadsheetApp) but you can still flush it by using **saveAndClose** and then re-opening the document (for example with document=DocumentApp.openById("myid")

saveAndClose is automatically called when a script finishes, but not after every change you make as Google batches those changes for performance.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document

Comment: Still showing as doc closed.    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  text.appendText(content[i]);
// Utilities.sleep(200);
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
  Utilities.sleep(600);
  DocumentApp.openById('IDEGOESHERE');
}

Comment: you are not calling the APIs correctly. openById returns a document object which you should use, NOT DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()

Comment: Thanks, I changed to openbyid and I am still seeing the closed error.

Comment: thats not where you add code. I rejected it. Edit your question instead, with proper code formatting. I saw that code and is still incorrect, you dont save anywhere the return of openById not you attempt to make a modification afterwards, so it couldnt possibly work either way. I just made my answer more explicit. Please study the docs well for each of the methods used, you will see correct usage there too.

Comment: This is not my question. Was just testing out your answer.  Add some code to your answer it would be more helpful.

Comment: More code would indicate that the issue is with knowledge of javascript or using the APIs in general, not of the specific Google APIs being asked. Please read the forum guidelines to see why I rejected your answer suggestion. It was not at all an answer but your own attempt that you already knew didnt work, so why would I include it in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried @ZigMandel suggestion. It appears to work but the text is being typed from the left out.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Start', 'myFunction')
        .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function myFunction() {
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var text = body.editAsText();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=title&grnlimit=1');
    var json = JSON.parse(response);

    for (key in json.query.pages) {
        var title = json.query.pages[key].title;
    }
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=&titles=' + title
    var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json2 = JSON.parse(response2);
    for (key in json2.query.pages) {
        var content = json2.query.pages[key].extract;
    }

    //format(content);
    //var par1 = body.insertParagraph(0, title);
    //par1.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    var str = "Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow."
    var split = str.split("");
    for (var i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        text.appendText(split[i]);
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
        body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
        text = body.editAsText();
    }
}

function format(txt) {
    txt = '\n' + txt;
    txt = txt.replace(/\===(.+?)\===/g, "").replace(/\==
(.+?)\==/g,"").replace(/\n+/g, "\n").replace(/\n/g, "\n" + "            ");
    return txt;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the script to print out each character with a delay between, you can put your sleep method into a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  text.appendText(content[i]);
  Utilities.sleep(200);
}
```

I think this gives you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: This also does not appear to work- It seems as though the sleep is working but it does not visually show the letters untill the script times out.